# (Android) Open Google Maps with a search and default bookmarks?

Tags: android

I'm putting together an application, where one of the buttons opens Google Maps. The idea is that when Google Maps opens, it will open with a default search, I mean, when it opens it will open with the search, for example, "ice cream shops" and in this way the user will know what ice cream shops are in their area. How is it done? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Using [Google Place Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?csw=1)

First Of all Call Google Place Api and find All "ice cream shops" near by you, it return list of shop with Lat and long

After result getting from place api add all marker on your google map

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Search for ice cream shops nearby
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=ice+cream+shops");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#categorical_search)